How to display all outputs from a step within github-script action
I understand you can get a particular output from a Github Actions job step by e.g. ${steps.captureStatus.outputs.response} (for step ID captureStatus). For debug purposes, I would love to be able to loop through ALL outputs from that step. The following code doesn't work:
- name: Display output
  run: |
    for message in ${{ steps.captureStatus.outputs }}; do
      echo "$message"
    done

What have I been doing wrong?

Try something like:
- name: Dump GitHub Actions context
  run: |
    echo "Dumping context for debugging"
    env

Or:
- name: Display all outputs as JSON
  run: |
    echo "${{ toJSON(steps.captureStatus.outputs) }}"


The content of steps.<step-id>.outputs is not directly compatible with a shell for-loop, since it's an object (attempting to echo the content will print a literal "Object" string). For the following content:
{
  "key1": "foo",
  "key2": "bar"
}

you could print the values using * expansion as follows (this won't display the keys though):
- name: Display output values
  run: |
    printf "${{ join(steps.create-output.outputs.*, '\n') }}"

This would print:
foo
bar


Really, nice, clean output. Almost gave it the green tick, but the other answer turned out to be what I went with
